# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string - dynamic query versus static query

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past one or two hours, searching on stackoverflow and elsewhere for an answer.

When I use this code everything runs fine:

```
    $songs = Song::query()->whereHas('categories', function ($id) {
        $id->where("categories.title", "terrible");
    })->get();
```

But as soon as my query is dynamic (**"terrible"** ===> **$id**), I get a bug:

```
    $songs = Song::query()->whereHas('categories', function ($id) {
        $id->where("categories.title", $id);
    })->get();
```

The error message I get is:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In callback as agrgument Laravel pass Builder instance. If you want get some var from parent scope - you must use "use" statement

```
$id = 1;
$songs = Song::query()->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where("categories.title", $id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. `$q` is the query object and `use ($title)` lets you solve the context of your search.

```
$songs = Song::query()->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($title) {
    $q->where("categories.title", $title);
})->get();
```

That error it's because that the param in the function is the builder.